# How to extract values from API response

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json


def getAPIreturn(para):
    url = "http://localhost/search?name={}".format(para)
    try:
        return_json = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
        response = return_json['data'] # get the first response string
        print (type(response))
    except:
        response = "" 
    return response

data = pd.read_csv("input.csv") 
data['return'] = data['para'].apply(getAPIreturn)

data.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

The above code will read a csv file and read the first column named `input` for calling the API as a parameter then get the `data` back and save into the second column named `return` and output a CSV file.

What if I want to select multiple values from the response? For example, `score`, `count`, `status` and save it back into CSV?

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "score": 1234
        },
        {
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "Section": "abc",
            "DisplayName": "hihi",
            "status": "History"
        }
    ]
}
```

preferred result in the csv file:

| input | score | count | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| para | score1 | 1 | History |
| para2 | score2 | 2 | History |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using apply on a given column, you could use apply on the whole dataframe and pass `axis=1`. Your function will be called once per row. The row can then be updated as required with the results from the request, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

def getAPIreturn(row):
    para = row['para']
    url = f"http://localhost/search?name={para}"
    
    try:
        return_json = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
        data = return_json['data']
        
        score = data[0]['score']
        count = data[1]['count']
        status = data[2]['status']
    except:
        score = None
        count = None
        status = None
        
    row['score'] = score
    row['count'] = count
    row['status'] = status
        
    return row

data = pd.read_csv("input.csv") 
data = data.apply(getAPIreturn, axis=1)
data.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

You could also probably use the following:

```
return_json = requests.get(url).json()
```

Comment: data['score'], data['count'], data['status'] = data['para'].apply(getAPIreturn) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2), not sure what happened.

Comment: yep, 3 [1, 1, 'History'] para  ,3 [2, 10, 'History'] para2

Comment: Original csv
| input   | 
| --------| 
| para    | 
| para2   | 

I got two rows for input, when I add one more row, the error solved, but it seems like the no. of input(para)  should equal the no. of column from score, count and status(no less or more). In case, I want 3 values from the list,then my input para should have 3 items in the csv, I want to get value back based on the no. of  "para" that I have in the csv file.

Comment: I have updated the solution, hopefully this works better